# How to pass dynamically created hyperlink's css value to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm beginner in web development. I'm stuck in passing dynamic value 
to another page when it was clicked. The only thing I need is to get clicked 
hyperlink's value in another page. Please help me with this.

First page:

```
@for (int j = 0; j < listOfUrls.Count; j++)
{
    <a style="background: #fff url(@listOfUrls[j]) no-repeat center;"
       href="nextPage" 
       onclick="@*Pass clicked listOfUrls[j]*@" ></a>
}
```

Next page:

`<p>@*Here I need to get the clicked value of hyperlink from previous page*@</p>`

Comment: The previous page has been gone for a while ago, it simply doesn't exist.

Comment: You may try use query string to pass value

Comment: Hmm... maybe I've slightly misunderstood the question. If you want to pass something from the __current__ page to the next page, that really can be done by the query string like Den already has suggested.

Comment: I've already using Sessions to pass a value. But when I do so, it's passing only the last item of the `listOfUrls`. That's why I was thinking using of OnClick to handle the CLICKED index and pass the value of that index.

Comment: Or maybe there is another way to handle the index of clicked dynamic hyperlink...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a simple controller for showing demo.

> Demo Controller

From this Controller, I am sending the collection to View.

```
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    // GET: Demo
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<DemoModel> list = new List<DemoModel>()
        {
            new DemoModel {Id = "1", Link = "One"},
            new DemoModel {Id = "2", Link = "Two"},
            new DemoModel {Id = "3", Link = "Three"},
            new DemoModel {Id = "4", Link = "Four"}
        };

        return View(list);
    }
}
```

Values which I am going to send to Next page is ID in that I am sending the value of a link.

```
@model  List<WebApplication9.Models.DemoModel>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
               {
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Demo2", new {@id = Model[i].Link})">
                        #Link to Page @Model[i].Link
                    </a>

                    <br />
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Rendering View

[image]

We are Sending values to Demo2Controller in which it has Index Action Method which take ID as input.

```
public class Demo2Controller : Controller
{
    // GET: Demo2
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            TempData["message"] = id;
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["message"] = "Not Clicked";
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

> Index View (Demo2)

```
    @{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <strong>Success!</strong> @TempData["message"]
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]